# Boost::Asio Async UDP Server - Unhandled Exception Message

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I am fairly new to C++ programming, coming from a background in embedded C. I am trying to put together a project with a UDP receiver using Boost::Asio and when debugging the code I receive an 'Unhandled exception' dialog in MS Visual Studio Express 2012.

**Is this really an error or simply run-time feedback because I do not have exception handling code?**

I have a singleton class called UDP_Listener that initiates an async_receive_from on a socket member variable. In my main thread of execution, I spawn another thread to execute io_service::run() and create the instance of UDP_Listener.

This is the code from the main thread of execution that creates the network object:

```
// UDP listener initialisation
try{
    // io_service and the work object to keep it from returning immediately
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    // Spawn a new thread to execute the io_service run() method
    boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    // Create the UDP listener object - singleton class
    m_pListener = new UDP_Listener(io_service);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The UDP_Listener class has the header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "boost_1_58_0/boost/array.hpp"
#include "boost_1_58_0/boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost_1_58_0/boost/bind.hpp"

#include "Target.h"

class UDP_Listener
{
public:
    // Constructor
    UDP_Listener(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);

    // Destructor
    ~UDP_Listener(void);

    // Start an async receive from the member socket
    void asyncReceive(void);

    // Create a list of target objects from the received byte array
    void buildTargetList(void);

private:

    void handleReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error, 
        std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/);

    void handleSend(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/,
      const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/);

    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_remote_endpoint;

    // Received byte array
    boost::array<signed char, 8192> m_recv_buffer;

    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;

    // List of target objects most recently received
    std::vector<Target> m_target_list;

    // The distance resolution (16 metres / 2^7 bits representation)
    FLOAT d_step;// = 0.125f;
    // The speed resolution (15.3 km/h / 2^7 signed bits)
    FLOAT s_step;// = 0.24f;
};
```

and the implementation(simplified here to remove irrelevant functions):

```
#include "UDP_Listener.h"

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

/// <summary>
/// Constructor
/// </summary>
UDP_Listener::UDP_Listener(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
    : m_io_service(io_service),
      m_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 12345))
{
    d_step = 0.125f;
    s_step = 0.24f;

    // Start listening for UDP packets
    asyncReceive();
}

/// <summary>
/// Destructor
/// </summary>
UDP_Listener::~UDP_Listener(void)
{
    //m_io_service.stop();
    m_socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::shutdown_both);
    m_socket.close();
}

/// <summary>
/// Start listening for UDP packets
/// </summary>
void UDP_Listener::asyncReceive()
{
    m_socket.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer), m_remote_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&UDP_Listener::handleReceive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

/// <summary>
/// Handler for received packets
/// </summary>
void UDP_Listener::handleReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
{
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
        if (m_recv_buffer[0] == 0x19 && m_recv_buffer[1] == 0x73)
        {   
            m_target_list.clear();
            buildTargetList();
        }
        asyncReceive();
    }
}
```

When compiling and executing with the VS debugger, I get this message:
`boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x0674F180.`

I am afraid I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, considering I am inexperienced with networking, thread management and C++ with an OS. I do not want to proceed in my application with intrinsically flawed coding!

Comment: Try creating the UDP listener object before spawning the thread to call io_service run in your main thread.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I see is that you are calling the ioservice run on a separate thread before you give it asynchronous work to do. This will cause that run method to immediately exit out and your asynchronous call will never fire because the io service is not running. Also I would call the ioservice run with an error code so you can catch any errors like this:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service, ec));
if (ec)
//do error checking here
```

Another place where errors are likely to occur is when a socket is bound. You are binding the socket using its constructor to port 12345 but what happens if that port already has a socket bound to it? what if you dont have permission to bind to a port? It is good practice to pass error codes and handle them. Here is an example:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::ip::address_v4 address = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any();
boost::asio::udp::endpoint ep(address, 12345)
boost::asio::udp::socket sock(io_service);
sock.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), ec);
if (ec)
    //do error checking here
sock.bind(ep, ec);
if (ec)
    //do error checking here

//now do any reads or writes
```

The exception you are getting is the result of not handling one of these boost error codes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand that it's bad practise not to use error checking and exception handling but I this is an extremely rushed project I am hacking together for a product demonstration. Anyway, I solved (or worked around) this original issue by using blocking IO in a dedicated thread, not ideal but it is functional. If I have time, I will take another look at an async approach. I fear I may also have been attempting to access private members directly at some stage.